# How to set run a SQL query every 10 minutes

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a SQL Plus query that I wish to run and loop, what would be the simplest way to make it so it runs every 10 minutes?

I don't want to use Task Scheduler, I want this to be something that I can manually invoke and monitor, and stop if need be. What would I need to add to the query to do this?

Edit: Edited question to make it clearer.

Comment: Can you create the job using SQL Agent and just pause it, and run it manually as needed? There is nothing innate in ANSI SQL that involves scheduling, but the Agent should work.

Comment: Running a SQL query every ten minutes has nothing to do with SQL. _the simplest way_ depends on your environment and configuration and you have provided no details regarding either. You mention _Task Scheduler_ which implies to me that you are on Windows. Why do you feel that _Task Scheduler_ is not suitable? Maybe it is and you are mistaken?

Comment: What the jobs are is irrelevant, I probably should have said less. All that's relevant is that I have an SQL Plus query that I wish to run every 10 minutes. I do not want to use Task Scheduler since I want it to be invoked manually, and something that can cancelled easily. I am open to other suggestions outside of adding a loop command or something to the query, ie using Powershell, but am trying to keep it as easy as possible for the rest of my team to understand and modify if they wish to.

Comment: Are you referring to Oracle's [SQL*Plus](https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Plus)?

Comment: Yes, that's the one.

Comment: Have you considered [DBMS_SCHEDULER](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72235)?

Answer (score 0):

If your using SQL Server, My suggestion is "SQL Server -Jobs", Please find the steps for Job creation on below URL

```
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/execute-stored-proc-using-sql-job/
```

Above Article has clear steps for creating jobs with scheduler mode. If you want Manually run job, Please keep your job in stop status whenever you need just executed/Start.. That's it your work will done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a batch file.

Put your query into a SQL script and then using something along the lines:

```
:run_query
  sqlplus your_user/your_password@your_tns_name @scriptfile.sql
  timeout /T 600
  goto :run_query
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for though it doesn't repeat, it'll just run the once and that's it.

Comment: No, it's an endless loop that runs `sqlplus` every ten minutes

Comment: Yes, I know it should be, but it's not looping. It'll run the query once upon opening, then that's it.

Comment: No idea, works for me. Is `sqlplus` maybe another batch file you are running?

Comment: So what would be required to run it as a powershell script instead of a batch file?